# Is it a pronunciation mistake in Trump's inauguration speech?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

Did Trump here mistakenly pronounce the "~ing ou~" of

> We must protect our borders from the ravages of other countries mak**ing ou**r products, stealing our companies, and destroying our jobs.

as /ɪ**n** aʊ/, instead of /ɪ**ŋ** aʊ/?
[Trump Inauguration Speech (FULL) | ABC News, t=570s](https://youtu.be/sRBsJNdK1t0?t=570)

Comment: This can be answered by a dictionary, which will show you the correct pronunciation of any word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/ɪn/ is a well-known, fairly casual pronunication of "ing". It's familiar enough that it is sometimes represented as *makin'* with an apostrophe. It is on a similar level of informality as using "gonna" for "going to".

This kind of informality is typical of how some politicians speak. Perhaps they want to sound more like the "common man" by using these kind of contractions.  I would not call this a "mispronunciation". Nevertheless, the formal pronunciation is /ɪŋ/

Comment: Thanks! Just to make sure I didn't mishear it, do you think Trump pronunced /ɪn aʊ/ instead of /ɪŋ aʊ/ when he said "making our products" in that video?

Comment: My ears aren't good enough to tell the difference.  There's no contrast here between two words that would have different meaning.  That is, if he had pronounced "fang" as "fan" I might hear the difference.  But because makin' and making mean the same, I don't hear it, in flowing speech.  My brain has autocorrect turned on.  You might need to ask someone who doesn't speak English, but who does have both sounds in their language.